# Do we need a hats tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

So, this question was made: [Why do games have hats?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/128717/why-do-games-have-hats)

With the question the tag [hats](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hats) was made, before starting rollback wars do we really need such a tag?

Would a tag like [cosmetics-customization](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmetics-customization) be better?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We definitely do not need a `hats` tag and I have removed it from the question.

Comment: But think of the hats!

Answer (score 14):

We certainly don't need a tag for [hats](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hats).

Although [cosmetics-customization](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmetics-customization) could do the trick, seeing the scope of the answers, it's not only used for that as it could be used as [trophies](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trophies) and/or *visual achievement* as well.

Answer (score 1):

I sincerely think we need a hats tag.  I love hats and I constantly refresh to see if there are any new hat related questions.  Please do not remove the hats tag, I use this hourly.

Comment: Hourly not often enough. -5.

Comment: Looking at score, you can tell some people don't get the joke.

Comment: Without the hats tag I'm not sure if I can get through a workday.

Comment: Hats.... Hats everywhere

Answer (score -2):

Why stop at hats?  What about other clothing-based modifications?  Perhaps we should have a `dapper` tag, instead...

Comment: Wow, tongue-in-cheek comments don't go over so well here in meta...

Comment: Your not making a comment, your posting an answer. Downvotes are used to simply show users do not agree with you. It is worth being aware that without tone, it is easy to misread when a user is legitimately having a laugh, trolling, or just voicing an unpopular opinion.